# Android Mediaplayer volume fluctuates

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, volume

I'm currently working on an app that has to play audio. I have a method that plays a series of .mp3's in order. Here is the method:

```
/**
 * Plays a series of sounds in order without delay.
 * 
 * @param audioResourceIds
 *          An in-order array of the audio asset resources to play.
 * */
public void playQueuedPlaylist(int[] audioResourceIds)
{
    float lastPlayedSoundDuration;

    for(int i = 0; i<audioResourceIds.length; i++)
    {
        lastPlayedSoundDuration = playMedia(audioResourceIds[i], null);
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep((long)lastPlayedSoundDuration);
        }
        catch(Exception eh)
        {
            Log.v("BulacsAlmighty","Exception caught at playQueuedPlaylist()");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Used to play voice overs
 * 
 * @param index
 *            id of the sound
 * @param listener
 *            on completion listener
 */

public int playMedia(int index, OnCompletionListener listener) 
{

    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, index);
    mp.setVolume(streamVolume, streamVolume);


    stopMedia(index); // Stops the sound if it still is playing.

    mp.start();

    return mp.getDuration();
}
```

**The problem is that the sounds sometimes do not play.** And when they play, the timing is correct, the order is correct, **but the last audio resource played is played at a significantly lower volume than the other sounds played before it.**

Tell me, where did I go wrong!?

Comment: Have you played these mp3s in an external music player to verify they are all about the same volume?

Comment: As a matter of fact I did. I even have test buttons which can play each sound individually. They all play at the same volume except when used in the context of the methods mentioned above.

Comment: Just for debugging purposes, what if you switch the order of the tracks? Then will it still be just the last which volume is quieter?

Comment: Yes, I tried that too it still behaves as is. :(

Answer (score 0):

How are you stopping the previous tracks if you are not storing and releasing the associated `MediaPlayer` for that track? How does `stopMedia` work?

`setVolume` will fail if the `MediaPlayer` is on the *Error* state. Please set `On<Event>Listeners` so that you can really find out what is happening with the previously played `MediaPlayer`s. Particularly, you might be interested in implementing `OnInfoListener` and `OnPreparedListener`.

Also, how is `streamVolume` modified? You might have a race condition somewhere and that code might be setting `streamVolume` preemptively. Please check all code that are modifying `streamVolume`.

Answer (score 0):

Just curious  why do you call

> mp.setVolume(streamVolume, streamVolume);

at all? Is it really necessary? You don't mention why the volume needs to be adjusted from code.

Comment: Oh, about that. I have this code somewhere else that the volume is increased or decreased dynamically depending on other sounds playing. In the code you quoted, streamVolume is a 1. I tried commenting out this line, too, but to no avail.